# Why does it gives an error as undefined property in my model?

Tags: laravel, model

In my model the First method works fine but if second method is written it gives error as undefined property for is_finished property

```
//Model
protected $fillable = ['is_finished'];
protected $appends = [ 'is_recorded' ];

public function getIsRecordedAttribute()
{
    if($this->is_finished > 1){ // it can be 2,3
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//the below getIsFinishedAttribute() method gives an error message 
//that is Undefined property: App\Models\Backend\MeetingContent::$is_finished in file
public function getIsFinishedAttribute()
{
    if($this->is_finished > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can i fix my model? 
I don't want to show the is_finished property as it is because it can be higher than 1

Comment: `if($this->attributes['is_finished'] > 0)` have you tried this ? I don't exactly remember, but one day I had done something like this.

Comment: So does your model have a database column called `is_finished`? or are you trying to define an attribute called `is_finished` ?

Comment: @Spholt it's inside `$fillable` ofcourse it will be a database column

Comment: @Akhtar Munik you would think that but you should never assume anything. It's the first rule of QA. If this is an issue with the naming convention of the attribute and how it is being accessed, then the recursive call you have pointed out wouldn't be evident yet :P

Comment: @Spholt Exactly, but you know as a developer we should also judge someone from their code, like he has already use `$appends` and `$fillable`, We should think from his reputation on stack that he wouldn't do such kind of mistakes  You know sometimes we need to use commonsense :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization you should access the attribute in a different way

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['admin'] === 'yes';
}
```

so for your example

```
public function getIsRecordedAttribute()
{
    if($this->attributes['is_finished'] > 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


public function getIsFinishedAttribute()
{
    if($this->attributes['is_finished'] > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the point I don't understand is why it worked in the first and not in the other